# split dataframe into a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe containing 4 columns. I want to use 2 of the columns as keys for a dictionary of dictionaries, where the values inside are the remaining 2 columns (so a dataframe)

```
birdies = pd.DataFrame({'Habitat' : ['Captive', 'Wild', 'Captive', 'Wild'],
    'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon','Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.],
                  'Color': ["white", "grey", "green", "blue"]})
#this should ouput speed and color
birdies_dict["Falcon"]["Wild"]
#this should contain a dictionary, which the keys are 'Captive','Wild'
birdies_dict["Falcon"]
```

I have found a way to generate a dictionary of dataframes with a single column as a key, but not with 2 columns as keys:

```
birdies_dict = {k:table for k,table in birdies.groupby("Animal")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `defaultdict` for this, a solution for the 2 column problem is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for (hab, ani), _df in df.groupby(['Habitat', 'Animal']):
    d[hab][ani] = _df
```

This breaks with 2 columns, if you want it with a higher depth, you can just define a recursive defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
recursive_dict = lambda: defaultdict(recursive_dict)
dct = recursive_dict()
dct[1][2][3] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `to_dict` to the inside:

```
birdies_dict = {k:d.to_dict() for k,d in birdies.groupby('Animal')}
birdies_dict['Falcon']['Habitat']
```

Output:

```
{0: 'Captive', 1: 'Wild'}
```

Or do you mean:

```
out = birdies.set_index(['Animal','Habitat'])
out.loc[('Falcon','Captive')]
```

which gives:

```
Max Speed      380
Color        white
Name: (Falcon, Captive), dtype: object
```

Comment: This is using indexes, but I need it to be in form of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
birdies_dict = {k:{habitat: table[['Max Speed', 'Color']].to_numpy() for habitat in table['Habitat'].to_numpy()} for k,table in birdies.groupby("Animal")}
```

OR

```
birdies_dict = {k:{habitat: table[['Max Speed', 'Color']] for habitat in table['Habitat'].to_numpy()} for k,table in birdies.groupby("Animal")}
#In this case inner key will have a dataframe
```

OR

```
birdies_dict = {k:{inner_key: inner_table for inner_key, inner_table in table.groupby('Habitat')} for k,table in birdies.groupby("Animal")}
```

Comment: The inner key should be the second column, not "Habitat", I edited the question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Check the edited answer

Comment: this is indeed an answer to this very specific dataframe, but what im looking for is for a generalization, similar to the solution of a single column key

Comment: Sorry I didn't get this, what do you mean by `similar to the solution of a single column key`

Comment: This snippet creates a dictionary of dataframes, using column 'animal'  as keys,
```birdies_dict = {k:table for k,table in birdies.groupby("Animal")}```
 I am looking for a similar construct, but having 2 columns as keys, that is independent of the structure of the dataframe

Comment: May be you can use groupby two times, check my edited answer